# Django: outcommenting in templates

Tags: django

How can lines in a template be outcommented or otherwise be disabled (short of deleting the line)?

E.g. if file "base_weblog.html" contains:

> {% load ProgramVersion %}{% render_month_links %}

How can this line be hidden at runtime?

This does not work (e.g. TemplateSyntaxError if ProgramVersion is not a valid tag library - that is why I want to outcomment):

> {% if false %}
>
> {% load ProgramVersion %}{% render_month_links %}
>
> {% endif %}

**Update 1**. This solves it:

> {% comment %}
>
> {% load ProgramVersion %}{% render_month_links %}
>
> {% endcomment %}

Just curious: why is "load ProgramVersion" evaluated in the first case and not in the second? Is it too complicated to optimise for possibly nested control structures (and comments can not be nested)?
Note that "if false" above should have been "if False", but it makes no difference. With
a non-existing variable, say XYZ, load is still evaluated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments declared like this won't show up to users.

{% comment %} your comment text {% endcomment %}

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
{% comment %} .... {% endcomment %}
```

Consult the [Django template documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/).

Answer (score 3):

There is also a second option for comments. Nice for one-liners.

```
{# {% load ProgramVersion %}{% render_month_links %} #}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
{% comment %} 'this will not be displayed' {% endcomment %}
```

or

```
{# {{ form.as_p }} #}
```

NOTE: you cannot do this to comment out multiple lines of code:

```
{# <h1>Some header</h1>
{{ form.as_p }}
 #}
```

Every line of code that you want to comment out should be enclosed with this {# #}

```
{# <h1>Some header</h1> #}
{# {{ form.as_p }} #}
```